# How to export dataFrame csv/excel file to a specific directory

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

Databricks dataFrame

I have a dataFrame that I would like to export the result to a specific path/directory.

By doing `display(df)`, you got a button that you can press that will give you a download off the result that you can open in excel.

How can I do this by using python? I am trying to make a job in databricks that run in a specific schedule, and I want it to run my entire notebook, and in the end make it export the final result and save it in a specific directory so I can go back in time and see some old result.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the data to a CSV format(Which can be opened in Excel). In order to do so you can convert the DataFrame to a Pandas DataFrame and then convert it to CSV format.

```
df.toPandas().to_csv("<FILE_DESTINATION>/<FILE_NAME>")
```